# cannot find solution for error : formGroup expects a FormGroup instance in angularJS2

Tags: validation, angular

I am new to angularJS2, I am trying to build a form template using angularJS2 forms and do a validation in it but i am facing a error which i am not able to get the resolve it. I tried to include the FormBuilder.group() method in the constructor but i didnt solve the problem. this the error which i am getting
[image]
I have updated my code in [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/L7WyK4jTb0Eyn3ctViSk)
The following is my component code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'policy-form',
    templateUrl: '../../templates/policy.template.html'
})
export class PolicyComponent {
    policyForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.policyForm = fb.group({
            insuredName: ['', Validators.required],
            insuredAddress: ['', Validators.required],
            taxationType: ['', Validators.required],
            lastVersion: ['', Validators.required],
            renewal: ['', Validators.required],
            commissionType: ['', Validators.required],
            balanceDue: ['', Validators.required],
            suspenseAmount: ['', Validators.required],
            policyNumber: ['', Validators.required],
            policyType: ['', Validators.required],
            underwriter: ['', Validators.required],
            policyYear: ['', Validators.required],
            paymentPlan: ['', Validators.required],
            receivedDate: ['', Validators.required],
            enteredDate: ['', Validators.required],
            selectDate: ['', Validators.required],
            issueddate: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }

    SubmitPolicy(value: any) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a simple typo. You've declared the FormGroup instance as `policyForm` but in your template you are binding to `[formGroup]="PolicyForm"`. Just lowercase the first letter and the error will be gone.

Comment: thank you, you saved my day, angularJS2 shouldnt be this strict and complicated :)